# How to add an html id to a form_for tag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add an id tag to a form that I'm creating in rails. The beginning of the form has the following code:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

Is it possible for me to add an id to the form_for embedded ruby, or do I have to create a form_tag field and add the id there? If I have to create a form_tag field, how do I add the id and create the form_tag field properly? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

try this `<%= form_for @user, :url => "controller action url", :html => {:id => "Blabla"} do |f| %>`

**EDIT:**
If you don't want custom action URL then you can use this as well
`<%= form_for @user, html: {id: "BlaBla"} do |f| %>`

Comment: When I implement this code, the form loads, however I can no longer submit the form. Is there an alternative syntax that will allow me to process the form when I hit submit? Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can get more help from here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Answer (score 6):

One more way:     `<%= form_for @user, html: {id: :form_id } do |f| %>`

Answer (score 2):

This is new syntax

`<%= form_for @user, html: {id: "my_form"} do |f| %> <% end %>`