# how to add id to this rails form <%= form_for @admin do |f| %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problems to add the id="signup" to my form:
i had tried but it was not working .

```
<%= form_for @admin, :id => "signup" do |f| %>
```

it is not working .[How to add an html id to a form_for tag in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383727/how-to-add-an-html-id-to-a-form-for-tag-in-rails)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this under html in rails

```
<%= form_for @admin, :html => { :id => "signup" } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= form_for @admin, :html => {:id => 'signup'} do |f|%>
```